# how can i make this code that lets computer to choose word from wordList of 83667 words fastly?

Tags: performance, function, python-3.x, loops, data-structures

Provide the faster version of **compChooseWord(hand, wordList, n)** function.
here are some details.

wordList is List of 83667 words;

hand is {'a': 1, 'p': 2, 's': 1, 'e': 1, 'l': 1}

n is positive integer

```
SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES = {
    'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 3, 'd': 2, 'e': 1, 'f': 4, 'g': 2, 'h': 4, 'i': 1, 'j': 8, 'k': 5, 'l': 1, 'm': 3, 'n': 1, 'o': 1, 'p': 3, 'q': 10, 'r': 1, 's': 1, 't': 1, 'u': 1, 'v': 4, 'w': 4, 'x': 8, 'y': 4, 'z': 10
}

def getWordScore(word, n):

    score=0
    for i in word:
       if i in SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES:
           score=score+SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES[i]
    score=score*len(word)

    if len(word)==n:
       score=score+50

    return score
def isValidWord(word, hand, wordList):

    """
    Returns True if word is in the wordList and is entirely
    composed of letters in the hand. Otherwise, returns False.

    Does not mutate hand or wordList.

    word: string
    hand: dictionary (string -> int)
    wordList: list of lowercase strings
    """


    c=True
    wordCount=len(word)
    handCopy=hand.copy()
    for i in word:
         if i in hand:
            handCopy[i]=handCopy.get(i,0)-1
            wordCount=wordCount-1
            if handCopy[i]<0:
              c=False
              break

    b=word in wordList and wordCount==0

    return  b and c
```

**Provide alternate faster version to following functions**

```
def compChooseWord(hand, wordList, n):

    """
    Given a hand and a wordList, find the word that gives 
    the maximum value score, and return it.

    This word should be calculated by considering all the words
    in the wordList.

    If no words in the wordList can be made from the hand, return None.

    hand: dictionary (string -> int)
    wordList: list (string)
    n: integer (HAND_SIZE; i.e., hand size required for additional points)

    returns: string or None
    """

    bestScore = 0
    bestWord = None
    for word in wordList:
        if isValidWord(word, hand, wordList):
            score = getWordScore(word, n)
            if (score > bestScore):
                bestScore = score
                bestWord = word
    return bestWord
```

Comment: This sounds like homework... Is this home work? What have your tried to make it faster and what was the result? How bad is the current performance?

Comment: one easy thing would be to sort the wodlist by score. That way you can stop the loop as soon as you found a valid word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @mroman comment above: the easiest optimization there is jsut sorting the wordist in the reversed score value, and stop when you find the first word.

Python sorting is very efficient to things like this, as it allows the function `getWordScore` itsef be used as key for sorting, and it can even take in account your hand size when sorting - so your search would be:

```
def compChooseWord(hand, wordList, n):

    bestScore = 0
    bestWord = None
    wordList = sorted(wordList, key=lambda word: getWordScore(word, n))
    for word in wordList:
        if isValidWord(word, hand, wordList):
            break
    else:
         # No "break" means: end of the list with no word-matching
         return None
    return word
```

But, if that is not enough, you can also re-write `isValidWord` to be a bit faster, by first verifying if one does have the needed letters to form a word, using "set"s, and just fif so, verify the letter count using the more expensive method of checking the letter counts:

```
def isValidWord(word, hand, wordList):

    word_letters = set(word)
    if not word_letters.intersection(hand.keys()):
         # You don't have the needed letters to start with
         return False
    handCopy=hand.copy()

    for letter in word:
        handCopy[letter] -= 1
        if handCopy[letter] < 0:
            return False              

    return wordCount == 0
```

Note that if you are looping through "letters" in a "word" there is no
reason to name them "i" - just call them "letters". Second thing: you don't need much of the auxiliar variables you where carrying around, like 'wordCount': when the loop is over, you will have checked all the letters. And also, just return False, instead of setting an auxiliar (and badly named) `b` variable to indicate the match failed anyway

And as a bonus: you can use the enhanced assignment operator `-=` to avoid repeating an expression on both sides of the equality.